# Cheerio: group together multiple searches

Tags: web-scraping, cheerio

Let's say I want to find all `tr` elements, children of `tbody`, having either class `trEven` or `trOdd` (unfortunately there are also elements not having these classes). How can I get all of them in a single query?

I tried `$("tbody > tr.trOdd + tbody > tr.trEven")`
but it returns 0 elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use commas for multiple css selectors:

```
$("tbody > tr.trOdd,tbody > tr.trEven")
```

FTR, your css would have matched

```
tbody
  tr.trOdd
  tbody
    tr.trEven  <-- this one
```